# Read Azure AD User properties in a ASP.NET Core user request

Tags: asp.net, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

We use `schema extensions` in Azure Active Directory to attach additional information to an Azure Directory User.

Our IT uses simple PowerShell HTTP REST Calls against Microsoft Graph to write them.

What is the correct way to read them in a request in a ASP.NET Core API?
Do we have to configure something in the Azure AD to get the information as Custom Claim or do we have to use Microsoft Graph in this scenario?

I found some documentation like https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/extensibility_overview or https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/extensibility_schema_groups ...and then you can find a lot of old or archived GitHub links in the Microsoft documentation like https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-graphapi-directoryextensions-web

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ben, in an ASP.NET Core Web Api, you also need to use the Microsoft Graph, I believe.
We have not yet written a complete sample showing how to call the graph in a Web API, but you can have a look at this branch https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-aspnetcore-v2/tree/jmprieur/obo

the sample is a Web API, (exercised by a WPF app, but could be anything), which calls the Microsoft Graph in the name of the signed-in user.
The controller's lines to look at are those;
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-aspnetcore-v2/blob/jmprieur/obo/TodoListService/Controllers/TodoListController.cs#L105-L123

Then, once you get a token, you can call the graph the way it's described in the other docs

Comment: Don't hesitate to contact me if this does not help enough.

Comment: Thanks, Microsoft Graph was the right way. But the documentation is faulty / not clear and some parts are not documentation. So if you have a SPA and want to access an API: you can find samples and documentation. But if the API accesses Microsoft Graph, this scenario is very unclear in the documentation. The key was: you have to register your WebAPI as WebAPI and WebApp. Reason: as admin you only can set Org Consent if a reply URL exists. And a WebAPI does not have a Reply URL. I will work together with the Graph Team to make that part of the docs clear.

Comment: Maybe there is another solution to set Consents; but this was the only way we were able to access the Microsoft Graph as user to access user schema extensions. As admin it works without consent.